# CKeditor imageuploader imagebrowser wrong location

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ckeditor

I have CKeditor in

`E:\XAMPP\htdocs\projekt2\ck`

Wheh on Page with CKeditor I go to browser server

[image]

It opens wrong location to script in a popup

[image]

I don't know how is this even possible.

Everything is not on `http://localhost/projekt2/admin/ckeditor/plugins/`....

But on

`http://localhost/projekt2/ck`.....

And from there script is called

In PHP i called this by `<script src="<?= base_url('ck/ckeditor.js') ?>"></script>` which takes it from `http://localhost/projekt2/ck`

Answer (score 0):

The [imageuploader](http://ckeditor.com/addon/imageuploader) plugin you are using has default value for [filebrowserBrowseUrl](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-filebrowserBrowseUrl) config option (you can see it in the plugin source code - https://github.com/xsmo/Image-Uploader-and-Browser-for-CKEditor/blob/master/plugin.js).

To use different upload dir, change [filebrowserBrowseUrl](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-filebrowserBrowseUrl) config, e.g:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
    filebrowserBrowseUrl = 'http://localhost/projekt2/ck/.../imgbrowser.php';
} );
```